# What is the algorithm used in sort method in dart?

Tags: dart

I found out that dart language has a built-in sort method in List class and I would like to know what is the algorithm they used in this method and what is the Big O notation of it?

Comment: Try it yourself :-)

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/

Comment: BTW I think you meant `list.sort((String a, String b) => a.compareTo(b));`, and yes I get `[age, apple, banana, bob]

Comment: My second comment explains that!  You had a syntax error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> I found out that dart language has a built-in sort method in List class and I would like to know what is the algorithm they used in this method and what is the Big O notation of it?

If we take a look inside the SDK we can find the following implementation of the `sort` method on `List`:

```
  void sort([int compare(E a, E b)]) {
    Sort.sort(this, compare ?? _compareAny);
  }
```

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/b86c6e0ce93e635e3434935e31fac402bb094705/sdk/lib/collection/list.dart#L340-L342

Which just forward the sorting to the following internal helper class:

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/a75ffc89566a1353fb1a0f0c30eb805cc2e8d34c/sdk/lib/internal/sort.dart

Which has the following comment about the sorting algorithm:

```
/**
 * Dual-Pivot Quicksort algorithm.
 *
 * This class implements the dual-pivot quicksort algorithm as presented in
 * Vladimir Yaroslavskiy's paper.
 *
 * Some improvements have been copied from Android's implementation.
 */
```

This sorting algorithm is actually the same used in Java (at least Java 7):

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/DualPivotQuicksort.java.html

Here we can see that the O-notation is mostly `O(n log(n))`:

```
    * This class implements the Dual-Pivot Quicksort algorithm by
    * Vladimir Yaroslavskiy, Jon Bentley, and Josh Bloch. The algorithm
    * offers O(n log(n)) performance on many data sets that cause other
    * quicksorts to degrade to quadratic performance, and is typically
    * faster than traditional (one-pivot) Quicksort implementations.
```

For more details you can read the paper by the designer of the Dual-Pivot Quicksort algorithm:

https://web.archive.org/web/20151002230717/http://iaroslavski.narod.ru/quicksort/DualPivotQuicksort.pdf

But, also please note that Dart also has the following constant:

```
  // When a list has less then [:_INSERTION_SORT_THRESHOLD:] elements it will
  // be sorted by an insertion sort.
  static const int _INSERTION_SORT_THRESHOLD = 32;
...
  static void _doSort<E>(
      List<E> a, int left, int right, int compare(E a, E b)) {
    if ((right - left) <= _INSERTION_SORT_THRESHOLD) {
      _insertionSort(a, left, right, compare);
    } else {
      _dualPivotQuicksort(a, left, right, compare);
    }
  }
```

So for small lists, it makes more sense to use the traditional insertion sort algorithm which has a worst case big O of `О(n^2)`. But since the input are very small, it is properly faster than the Dual-Pivot Quicksort algorithm.

Comment: An interesting consequence of the "insertion sort for small lists" approach is that Dart's sort is *stable* for lists below length 32, but not for lists above. People sometimes try to check if the sort is stable, but only test with small lists and erroneously believe it to be so in general.

Answer (score 0):

At https://dartpad.dartlang.org/, try the following code.  I can't answer your question about what the implementation is under the covers, but you can bet it's O(n log n).

I'm using an answer because I can't supply code in a comment easily.

```
void main() {
  Map<String, int> map = {'a': 1, 'b': 2};

  List<String> list = ['banana', 'apple', 'age', 'bob'];

  list.sort((String a, String b) => a.compareTo(b));
  print(list);
}
```

BTW `list.sort();` would give the same results since that custom comparitor is the same as the default.

Comment: Unfortunately that last comment *completely* changed the question :-) .  And you edited the question to be entirely different than when I answered it.  Your comment shouldn't actually change the nature of the question.  Please ask the question you really want to ask!