# Getting an element of a List of a Map with the highest value in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a field of Lists of maps with this structure. I want to get the Map with the highest amount in this case the third map  {
amount: 400
name: "Joe"
id: "3df"
},

bids: [
{
amount: 200
name: "James"
id: "1df"
},
{
amount: 300
name: "Joseph"
id: "2df"
},
{
amount: 400
name: "Joe"
id: "3df"
},
]

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> map= [ { 'amount': 200, 'name': "James", 'id': "1df" }, { 'amount': 300, 'name': "Joseph", 'id': "2df" }, { 'amount': 400 ,'name': "Joe" ,'id': "3df" }, ];
  map.sort((a, b) => b['amount'].compareTo(a['amount']));
  print(map[0]);
```

if you dont want to mess with your original map order, create a temporary map and sort it to get your desired element.

Answer (score 0):

**Preserving List Order**

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> bids= [ { 'amount': 200, 'name': "James", 'id': "1df" }, { 'amount': 300, 'name': "Joseph", 'id': "2df" }, { 'amount': 400 ,'name': "Joe" ,'id': "3df" }, ];

if (bids.isNotEmpty) {
var max = bids[0];
bids.forEach((item) {
if (item['amount'] > max['amount']) max = item;
});
print(max['amount']);
print(bids);
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Dart `List.sort` has a `O(nLog(n))` time complexity according to this guess [What is the algorithm used in sort method in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60312504/what-is-the-algorithm-used-in-sort-method-in-dart)

You can achieve this with a `O(N)` time complexity (faster) and constant memory complexity without mutating your initial list as follow:

```
  void main() {
    double maxBid = getMaxBid([
      {'amount': 200, 'name': "James", 'id': "1df"},
      {'amount': 300, 'name': "Joseph", 'id': "2df"},
      {'amount': 400, 'name': "Joe", 'id': "3df"},
    ]);
    print("Max Bid is $maxBid");
  }

  double getMaxBid(List<Map<String, dynamic>> bids) {
    double maxBid = -double.infinity; // or zero depending on your bid range
    for (var bid in bids) {
      double bidAmount = bid["amount"];
      if (bidAmount <= maxBid) continue;
      maxBid = bidAmount;
    }
    return maxBid;
  }
```